# Distributed networks with microservices

Tags: asp.net, social-networking, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I'm reading a lot about microservices and there use cases. Azure Service Fabric is a great framework to develope such services.

I found this nice usage pattern from Service Fabric:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-pattern-distributed-networks-and-graphs/

In this example there is one microservice type representing an user as a reliable stateful actor. Each user is an instance of that service.

So if I have thousends of users, I will have thousends of actor instances. Like in Facebook I can update my feed and the feed of my friends very easy. For example, the state of an user actor service stores my social feed and the social feed of my friends with entries of our social states. That makes it very easy to get these informations very fast with low latency to display it and so on.

That is working very well, because an user hasn't normally thousends of friends. I would like to know where you would store the public feed with entries of social states which are for all users available? E.g. I could iterate over all user actor instances and get alle states. But that would't be very fast, because you have to find all actor instances and so on. Is there any pattern or best practice to do something like that? Maybe as another stateful service type representing the social states which are available for public? When an user updates his social state, he will automatically update the feed of his friends like in the service fabric example and he could also update the "public" feed if the new social state is for public. Now every user can get all (maybe filtered) public social states in addition to his own feed and his friends feed.

Would that be a good way to implement such a function? A client (user) would connect to his actor service instance and request the whole feed. The actor service instance would connect to the public service instance and request the filtered public feed entries. Then the actor instance would merge these entries with his own entries and give it back to the user to display the data. Or should the client connect each servcie (the public service instance and the user actor service instance) directly and the results would be merged on client side.

```
Client --getFeed--> UserActorService --getFeed--> PublicService
```

or

```
       --getFeed--> PublicService
Client|
       --getFeed--> UserActorService
```

If you know any best practices or trade offs with such problems, please point me in the right direction.